Parsing protobuf payload with Firestore Eventarc notifications and Google Cloud Run + Kotlin/Ktor
I have a very simple Kotlin/Ktor docker image that does this:
import com.google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.DocumentEventData

fun Application.configureRouting() {
  val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(javaClass)

  routing {
    post("/debugfirestore") {
      val message = call.receive<ByteArray>()
      val data = DocumentEventData.parseFrom(message)
      logger.info("documentEventData: $data")
      return@post
    }
  }
}

fun Application.configureSerialization() {
  install(ContentNegotiation) {
    json()

    @OptIn(ExperimentalSerializationApi::class)
    protobuf()
  }
}

I also have Eventarc and Firestore configured like this:
% gcloud eventarc triggers update my-firestore-update \
   --location=nam5 \
   --service-account=... \
   --destination-run-service=my-prototype \
   --destination-run-region=us-central1 \
   --destination-run-path="/debugfirestore" \
   --event-filters="database=(default)" \
   --event-filters-path-pattern="entity=test-collection/**" \
   --event-filters="type=google.cloud.datastore.entity.v1.written"

I'm running my app on Google Cloud Run. I can successfully trigger and receive an event but I'm unable to parse the protobuf payload (I think it's protobuf?).
com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException: Protocol message had invalid UTF-8.
    at com.google.protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException.invalidUtf8(InvalidProtocolBufferException.java:149)
    at com.google.protobuf.Utf8$UnsafeProcessor.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:1365)
    at com.google.protobuf.Utf8.decodeUtf8(Utf8.java:318)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readStringRequireUtf8(CodedInputStream.java:788)
    at com.google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.Document$Builder.mergeFrom(Document.java:854)
    at com.google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.Document$Builder.mergeFrom(Document.java:655)
    at com.google.protobuf.CodedInputStream$ArrayDecoder.readMessage(CodedInputStream.java:844)
    at com.google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.DocumentEventData$Builder.mergeFrom(DocumentEventData.java:615)
    at com.google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.DocumentEventData$1.parsePartialFrom(DocumentEventData.java:1290)
    at com.google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.DocumentEventData$1.parsePartialFrom(DocumentEventData.java:1282)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parsePartialFrom(AbstractParser.java:135)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:168)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:180)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:185)
    at com.google.protobuf.AbstractParser.parseFrom(AbstractParser.java:25)
    at com.google.events.cloud.firestore.v1.DocumentEventData.parseFrom(DocumentEventData.java:360)

The data that I'm writing to Firestore is simple JSON object without any crazy characters (AFAICT). Why is it complaining about UTF8? I'm guessing there's a problem with the way that I'm trying to parse the request payload OR the response isn't in the format (ByteArray) that I think it is. Where am I going wrong?
edit: I also tried this:
    post("/debugfirestore") {
      logger.info("Content-Type = ${call.request.contentType()}")
      val data = call.receive<DocumentEventData>()
      logger.info("documentEventData: $data")
      call.respond("$data")
      return@post
    }

I thought this might work since I have the protobuf() plugin but it fails saying:

Caused by: kotlinx.serialization.SerializationException: Serializer for class 'DocumentEventData' is not found.

Further down I see logs saying:

Please ensure that class is marked as '@Serializable' and that the serialization compiler plugin is applied.


I've done this using GKE and Go(lang). The default content type is JSON not Protobuf and so you may need to revise your gcloud eventarc trigger to include --event-data-content-type="application/protobuf"

FWIW, I tried adding this: logger.info("Content-Type = ${call.request.contentType()}") and it does print out application/protobuf.

Are you familiar with protoc? You could try capturing the message from your code and using either an online decoder or more usefully protoc --decode with the schema to try to repro the deserialization and ensure you're receiving what you think you're receiving

I wrote this to show how to decode EventArc messages using protoc --decode

Your blog post made me realize that I was trying to deserialize to the wrong type; I needed to use EntityEventData, not DocumentEventData!
I am familiar with protoc btw but grateful that I ended up not needing it for such a simple task. ;)

The issue is that I needed to use EntityEventData instead of DocumentEventData.
Thanks to DazWilkin for the answer.
Side note, using the kotlinx-serialization way doesn't seem to work for me here because, I think, neither EntityEventData nor DocumentEventData are @Serializable.

How did you deserialise value and old_value from payload to just get the actual data, without the metadata, like excludeFromIndexes, etc.?
